# How to speed up SnowSQL file import from local to internal stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have around 200 json files that I need to import from local to 4 internal stages (Each 50 files to 1 internal stage) and each file is of around 125 MB.

Is there anyway I can use parallel snowsql instances using CMD to send these files to different stages parallelly? Plus if I increase the warehouse size will it make any difference on the speed? TIA

Comment: You mean you want to upload these files from your computer? Wondering if your bandwidth is the limiting factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few factors to consider:

1. SnowSQL will compress each file for you, if it isn't already, which takes CPU on the machine that is executing the `PUT` command.  If the files are already compressed, you'll want to specify the `AUTO-COMPRESS` parameter to `FALSE`.
2. The `PUT` command does have a `PARALLEL` parameter that can be used, but I typically recommend that this isn't more than the number of threads available on the machine you are running the `PUT` command from.
3. The size of your warehouse in Snowflake will have no effect on the speed of the `PUT` command.  It isn't involved in the process at all.
4. If you have more than 1 machine available that has access to all of your files, you can increase the parallelism by executing separate `PUT` commands on multiple machines.  In your case, probably 4 machines total would make sense.  However, at some point, you'll be limited by the amount of bandwidth of your network connection.